# Social Data Service: Problem reading comments and ratings with javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom, social

To read social info from the webservice i am using functions similar to this one:

```
function getAverageItemRating(itemUrl) {
    var avg=0;
    if(itemUrl){
        var soapEnv =
            "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'> \n" +
            "<soap12:Body>\n"+
                    "<GetRatingAverageOnUrl   xmlns='http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService'> \n"+
                        "<url>" + itemUrl + "</url>\n"+
                    "</GetRatingAverageOnUrl >\n"+
                "</soap12:Body>\n"+
            "</soap12:Envelope>"
        ;
        jQuery.ajax({
            headers: {
                "Accept": "text/xml",
                "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            async: false,
            url: "/_vti_bin/SocialDataService.asmx?op=GetRatingAverageOnUrl ",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError + "\nResponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                if(data){
                    avg=$(data).find("Average").text();   
                    if(avg.indexOf("INF")>=0){
                        avg=0;
                    }               
                }         
            }
        });
    }
    return avg;
}
```

This function works on my machine. The problem is i cannot replicate this in any other of the devboxes around.

I have checked the User profile service settings, the user profiles properties and so far they seem identical.

the error response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: serviceContext</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

there aren't many google results for sharepoint+serviceContext and the few useful articles about this i found were not helpful